# Error trying to add row to datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Hi i'm sure i had this working before, but now i'm getting the following error message:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll" "Conversion from string "" to type
>   'Double' is not valid."

Can anyone give me any hints on where i'm going wrong? I cant seem to spot the mistake

```
Private Sub btnBasket_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBasket.Click

        Dim Gat As String
        Dim Choc As String
        Dim Cheese As String
        gat = tbGateuQuantity.Text
        Choc = tbChocQuantity.Text
        Cheese = tbCheesecakeQuantity.Text


        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Gat) Then
            dgvBasket.Rows.Add(New String() {"Strawberry Gateu", lblGateuPrice.Text, tbGateuQuantity.Text, (lblGateuPrice.Text * tbGateuQuantity.Text)})
        Else

        End If

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Choc) Then

            dgvBasket.Rows.Add(New String() {"Double Chocolate", lblChocPrice.Text, tbChocQuantity.Text, (lblChocPrice.Text * tbChocQuantity.Text)})
        Else

        End If

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Cheese) Then

            dgvBasket.Rows.Add(New String() {"Cheesecake", lblCheesecakePrice.Text, tbCheesecakeQuantity.Text, (lblCheesecakePrice.Text * tbCheesecakeQuantity.Text)})
        Else

        End If
        'adds items to basket

    End Sub
```

To clarify it flags up the write lines and the error occurs when any of the quantities (tbGateuQuantity.text, tbChocQuantity.text and tbCheesecake.text) are left empty, and even when they are all filled it wont write the lines anymore.

Comment: Turn on Option Strict.  `lblCheesecakePrice.Text * tbCheesecakeQuantity.Text` is nonsensical - you are doing math on strings/text (`"pie" * "ball"`)

Comment: I completely understand what you mean but i'm pretty sure that part of the code worked at one point...

Comment: It will not even compile using `Option Strict`

Comment: Well i don't want to disagree with you, but i've got the code working now lol

Comment: add `Option Strict On` to the top of your code file and see all the errors.  Those are all potential runtime errors to make you scratch your head over like this one.  `Option Strict On` converts them to compile errors so you can fix them before they crash and burn your app.

Comment: i will try it now but honestly right now it's not crashing or running slow at all

Answer (score 0):

Could this be because you’re using the Text attributes of your labels and textboxes (e.g `tbGateuQuantity.Text` )? These are strings so multiplying two together for the subtotal when you’re adding them to the DataGridView would require that you cast them to a numerical type such as a double first, do the calculation, and then convert the answer back to a string so you can add it to the array.

Example -

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Gat) Then
    dgvBasket.Rows.Add(New String() {"Strawberry Gateu", lblGateuPrice.Text, tbGateuQuantity.Text, (CStr(CDbl(lblGateuPrice.Text) * CDbl(tbGateuQuantity.Text)))})
End If
```

Comment: Hi, the quantity and price do have their own sections, however i need to multiply them together to form a sub total column... this was the only way i could think to do it. Can you suggest another option?

Comment: Ah I was thinking you could set the sections to be numerical data types to make it easier to multiply for the subtotal - Having [done my research] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) I can see why they're all strings though. Have removed that from the answer but I still think if you cast your textbox and label values to doubles, multiply them, and then cast the answer back to a string that should help (might have worked previously if you had Option Strict off because the compiler might have _implicitly_ converted to a Double)